# How to capture opencart (1.5.1) order confirm event?

Tags: php, opencart

When `confirm(...)` (in `order.php`) is called by a payment method module how can I get notification of this event and run my own method to process the data for an accounting module(I need to parse the order and send it to quickbooks)?

I am aware I could place a call in the confirm method. However, because of the license I want to avoid modifying anything in the OpenCart code.

Anyone know how to hook into OpenCart order confirm events? Is there a built-in means of notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no hooking method in OpenCart that you could do this with. The correct method to achieve this would be to use [vQmod](http://vqmod.com) and add your code to the `confirm()` method as you've mentioned. That said, I'm not entirely sure what you are referring to with the license. You are free to modify the source code of OpenCart as you wish